# SharePoint 2010 workflows modification

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I can see my site collection workflows in `https://sharepoint.com/_layouts/wrkmng.aspx` location, but they are hidden in SPD (I'm on SP 2010). Any way to access them for modification? And sub-sites where we are using these workflows are not displaying anything.

Thank you,
Alex.